# Statistical analysis of neural net results

Tags: statistics, neural-networks

I have a language recognition neural net that will decide if a word or phrase is written in English, Spanish or German by going threw the phrase word by word and returning a percent confidence that the word is in each language (between zero and one).

Example:

===================input: math is cool ===================

[math is cool] -> [english: 90%, german: 7%, spanish: 6%]

So for the phrase "Math is cool", it would decide the likelihood that each word is in each language, average those percentages together and use those averages as it's final guess.

My issue is that words that are super common in one language, but still used somewhat often in one of the other languages are skewing my results. For example, the word "die" in German means "the", but "die" is also a pretty common English word. Because the training data used for the neural net is just copy and pasted from wikipedia pages, the word "die" appears super often in the German training data and the neural net has learned "die" as a strictly German word: [die] -> [english: 2%, german: 97%, spanish: 3%].

I need a way to analyze the data to negate the outlier "die" in the sentence "I don't want to die", without negating the high English results from the rest of the words.

P.S. I'm a rising sophomore in college working on a personal project, not a professional. I haven't taken any stat classes yet so this is a little beyond my area of expertise. I've tried a couple random guesses (like averaging the square roots and then squaring the result), but nothing that came even close to working. I apologize in advance if this is super easy or a dumb question.

Comment: I know little about neural nets, so this is a comment rather than an answer. Perhaps in your training sessions your net can learn that when "die" occurs often the probability of German increases. Same for "ein", which is a word only in German (not Spanish or English), And "a" is common in English, never appears in German.

Comment: What is the architecture of your network? Aside from that question, I think it would be reasonable to train separate algorithms to predict whether the word is from English or not, from German or not, etc. That way both the German and English algorithms may be 100% sure that the word is from the respective language, and then you can normalize the outputs and obtain something like 50/50 English/German. Otherwise, I think an algorithm based solely on the amount of the occurances of the word in texts should predict "die" to come from German.

Comment: @Serg I currently have an input layer, a hidden layer, and a output layer with three nodes (one for each language). Are you saying that I should instead implement three neural nets with 2 output nodes, with each neural net representing one language?

Comment: @Brett In some sense. Actually, In this case it would be enough to have just one output (because the other one may be obtained by subtracting the output from 1). This is called "one-versus-all" classification. But really, I think the architecture does not fit the problem. I don't think this net is capable of learning something much more complex than classifying words based on how often they occur in previous texts, and certainly incapable of classifying new words. By the way, what is the input of your net?

Comment: @Serg (continue my previous comment)...Wouldn't this still cause the same problem? Say I used the same training data consisting of English, German and Spanish texts to train the English-or-not-English neural net, the neural net would still learn that the word "die" is probably not an English word, right? (honestly asking, not trying to argue)

Comment: @Serg I input a bunch of text copied from wikipedia pages in each language. I have about 3000 words from each language which are fed into the neural net randomly.

Comment: @Brett. A few occurances of a word in a text should be enough for a net to learn that this word comes from the respective language. I mean, any reasonable classifier should predict  with almost total probability that a word comes from a language if this word occured in a text in said language at least once. The tricky part is classifying words which the net has never seen.

In what  form are the words fed to the net? Your net only accepts numerical inputs of fixed length, so how do you convert words to numbers and how do you feed texts to it?

Comment: @Serg I convert each letter in a word to a string of 26 0's or 1's such that all the values are zero except for the number corresponding to the letters place in the alphabet (i.e. the letter 'a' would be "10000000000000000000000000"). I do this for each letter in a word up to 10 letters (any word greater than 10 letters is ignored) and any word less than 10 letters is padded with 26 0's for every extra space. I then concatenate all of the texts together and feed in 50 random words at a time from any of the languages.